# Risk of injecting a malicious script/code?

Tags: xss, vulnerability, html

I was was inspecting elements in a website and I randomly stumbled onto this piece of code .

```
</style><meta name="add-styles-here"/><meta name="add-scripts-here"/></head><body><kbn-csp data="{&quot;strictCsp&quot;:false}">
```

Question : is there a chance to inject malicious code inside the data field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's the current state of the CSP configuration of Kibana and this value come from the configuration not the client side. You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/main/src/core/server/rendering/views/template.tsx) and the CSP configuration [here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/main/src/core/server/http/csp/config.ts).